# Mysql to JSON, how to get a nested array?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to get a JSON-file looking like this:

```
[
    [
    'Disease', [ latitude, longitude, magnitude, latitude, longitude, magnitude, ... ]
    ],
    [
    'Disease', [ latitude, longitude, magnitude, latitude, longitude, magnitude, ... ]
    ]
];
```

This is what I've done:

```
<?php

    $sqlDisease = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Disease FROM DiseaseData") or die(mysql_error());

    while($rowDisease = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlDisease)){

            $sqlData = mysql_query("
            SELECT lat, lng, magnitude 
            FROM DiseaseData 
            WHERE Disease = '".$rowDisease."'") 
            or die(mysql_error());

            while($rowData = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlData)){
                $data[] = array_values($rowData);
            }

            $result[] =  array_values($rowDisease, $data);

    }

    $json = json_encode($result);
    $file = 'testRes.json';
    file_put_contents($file, $json);
```

I end up with a JSON-file looking like this:

```
[null,null,null]
```

The problem probably lies within the nested while-loops or array_values(), but I can't figure out exactly where.

Comment: try to: `$data[] = implode($rowData);` instead of `array_values`

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your code

1. `mysql_fetch_assoc` return an array. To use it in sqls `where` statement you need to get value from it. Otherwise it will be serialized to string "Array", which is not the disease that you looking for.
2. `array_values` can take only 1. If you pass 2 parameters its dosn't extract any values (at least in php 5.6.21 it only print warning).
3. In `$data` variable you have an array of arrays like this 
   `[[lat,lng,magnitude],[lat,lng,magnitude],...]`. If you try to extract values from this array it will create new array which will be absolutely same as stored in `$data`. You need to merge all sub arrays.
   For exmaple like this `call_user_func_array( 'array_merge', $data );`
   or by merging them in inner while loop.

Next problems more about your code style.

4. [Mysql extension is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) its better to use Mysqli or PDO.
5. Mysql (also pdo and mysqli) has [method](http://mysql_fetch_row) that extract values as simple enumerated array. So you don't need to call `array_values`
   in inner loop.
6. [It's may be unsafe to pass string data (even if it comes from trusted source) into sql](http://It's%20may%20be%20unsafe%20to%20pass%20string%20data%20(even%20if%20it%20comes%20from%20trusted%20source)) without escaping special symbols.

Try use this.

```
$sqlDisease = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Disease FROM DiseaseData") or die(mysql_error());

$result = [];
while($rowDisease = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlDisease)){
        $theDisease = $rowDisease['Disease'];
        $sqlData = mysql_query("
        SELECT lat, lng, magnitude 
        FROM DiseaseData 
        WHERE Disease = '".mysql_real_escape_string($theDisease)."'") 
        or die(mysql_error());
        $data = [];
        while($rowData = mysql_fetch_row($sqlData)){
            $data[] = $rowData;
        }
        $mergedData = call_user_func_array( 'array_merge', $data );
        $result[] =  [$theDisease, $mergedData];
}

$json = json_encode($result);
$file = 'testRes.json';
file_put_contents($file, $json);
```

Comment: Actually there's still problems.
It seems like it doesn't select distinct values 
WHERE Disease = $theDisease.

And also $data[] just keeps growing.

So the JSON looks like this now:

`[
 ["Malaria", ["40.555", "-122.222", "0.5", "85.111", "-33.4444", "0.7"]],
 ["HIV", ["40.555", "-122.222", "0.5", "85.111", "-33.4444", "0.7","40.555", "-122.222", "0.5", "85.111", "-33.4444", "0.7"]],
]`

I tried to change $theDisease to $theDisease[] and then looping it through a for-loop, although that messed up the array structure.

Comment: Got it to work now, I added `unset($data)` after `$mergedData` at the end of the while-loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner select fails, because of

```
WHERE Disease = '".$rowDisease."'")
```

$rowDisease is an array. Try:

```
WHERE Disease = '".$rowDisease['Disease']."'")
```

And @Alex is right, your `$data` keeps growing, you have to reset it `$data = []`, before fetching more data from the inner query.

And btw, I'm sure, you'll find a way to fetch that data in one single query, and bring it into the desired array structure later.